# Visualize changes in Yield curves correlation matrix across time

Tags: python, r

I have a big dilemma! What could be a good way to visualise a correlation matrix overtime?

I would like to check what is the effect in change of the correlation matrix structure on a Delta-Normal parametric Value at risk.

I have a set of 252 daily correlation matrixes (50x50) where each coordinate represents a specific yield curve_tenor correlation against the other 49.
example: EUR_LIBOR_3m , EUR_LIBOR_6m , ... EUR_LIBOR_30y, USD_LIBOR_3m ... etc

Basically I have intra-curve and curve correlations in the same matrix.

Do you please know a way to approach efficiently this problem? and if so a good way to visualize the change of corr over time?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have 252 grids of 50 x 50, so a total of 630,000 data points. Even if your plot was a reasonable 800 x 800 pixels, you would have one pixel per data point, coloured according to value, and there would be no way to know which pixel belonged to which variable. Perhaps an animation showing the 50x50 grid changing over time is your best bet.

Comment: What is the intention of your visualization, to identify patterns or to communicate something? Either way, this is a pretty big haystack to explore. You might look at tools like the ‘feasts’ package if you want to extract notable features from the 2,500 different time series, and then perhaps highlight a small handful of interest.

Comment: actually I am thinking to split the matrix in smaller matrixes (intra-curves corr and over-curves corr) just to focus on 1 smaller problem. Then for intra curves corr (i.r eur_Libor_3m vs eur_Libor 1y) I could use a dimensionality reduction method maybe to explain how corr changes over time? Thanks  a lot